# What is value of self in rails initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have seen this in initializers in rails (config/initializers/foo.rb)

```
module foo
     module bar
         def self.biz
            @blahblah = "what am i"
         end
     end
end
```

How is self used?
What instance is @blahblah being attached to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self in ruby is a method on the class itself, not an object.

So if you have

```
class SuperHero
  def self.awesome?
    true
  end
end
```

Then you can call `SuperHero.awesome?`

In your example, you have added a class method to Foo::Bar

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def self.biz
      @blahblah = "what am i"
    end
  end
end
```

So you can call .biz on the class (which is a module Bar in the Foo module)

```
Foo::Bar.biz
 => "what am i"
```